# gradle error in flutter while adding dependancies

Tags: flutter

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Lenovo\Music\c\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Music\c\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command: C:\Users\Lenovo\Music\c\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: add your gradle file code to your question

Comment: Moved error output to monospaced callout